# NuGet Restore failing randomly with error code NU3037 and NU3028

Tags: docker, nuget, certificate, .net-6.0, nuget-package-restore

I am experiencing some unusual behavior when I build my .NET 6.0 API. Below is the error I'm receiving.

**Actual Error:**

> error NU3037: Package
> 'runtime.win-arm64.runtime.native.System.Data.SqlClient.sni 4.4.0'
> from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository
> primary signature validity period has expired. [C:\code\MyApi.sln]
>
> error NU3028: Package
> 'runtime.win-arm64.runtime.native.System.Data.SqlClient.sni 4.4.0'
> from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository
> primary signature's timestamping certificate is not trusted by the
> trust provider. [C:\code\MyApi.sln]

Complete log/error from build:

```
MSBuild version 17.4.0+18d5aef85 for .NET
Determining projects to restore...
   Package 'runtime.win-arm64.runtime.native.System.Data.SqlClient.sni 4.4.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': 
   Signature type: Repository
   Package 'runtime.win-arm64.runtime.native.System.Data.SqlClient.sni 4.4.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json':   Subject Name: CN=NuGet.org Repository by Microsoft, O=NuGet.org Repository by Microsoft, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
   Package 'runtime.win-arm64.runtime.native.System.Data.SqlClient.sni 4.4.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json':   SHA256 hash: 0E5F38F57DC1BCC806D8494F4F90FBCEDD988B46760709CBEEC6F4219AA6157D
   Package 'runtime.win-arm64.runtime.native.System.Data.SqlClient.sni 4.4.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json':   Valid from: 4/9/2018 7:00:00 PM to 4/14/2021 7:00:00 AM
 C:\code\MyApi\MyApi.csproj : error NU3037: Package 'runtime.win-arm64.runtime.native.System.Data.SqlClient.sni 4.4.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository primary signature validity period has expired. [C:\code\MyApi.sln]
 C:\code\MyApi\MyApi.csproj : error NU3028: Package 'runtime.win-arm64.runtime.native.System.Data.SqlClient.sni 4.4.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository primary signature's timestamping certificate is not trusted by the trust provider. [C:\code\MyApi.sln]
   Failed to restore C:\code\MyApi\MyApi.csproj (in 3.35 sec).
```

Anyone know the cause of this? And how do you fix it?

Note: This is happening at random; sometimes, but not usually, rerunning the  build fixes it. The build has been working without issue for months, and I recently started to see this error.

I am running dotnet publish command inside a Docker, if it matters.

DockerFile:

```
# escape=`
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2016
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]


# Node/npm Install
RUN write-host "*********** Install node,npm"
ENV NODE_VERSION 16.13.0
RUN Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile nodejs.zip -UseBasicParsing $('https://nodejs.org/dist/v{0}/node-v{0}-win-x64.zip' -f $env:NODE_VERSION); `
Expand-Archive nodejs.zip -DestinationPath C:\; `
Rename-Item -Path $('C:\node-v{0}-win-x64' -f $env:NODE_VERSION) -NewName 'C:\nodejs'
RUN SETX PATH C:\nodejs
RUN npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/


# Install webpack
RUN write-host "*********** Install webpack"
RUN npm install webpack@4.1.1 -g
RUN npm install webpack-cli@3.2.1 -g


# Add the shared for version build
RUN write-host "*********** Copy shared directory"
COPY shared \shared


# Verify installation
RUN dotnet --version
RUN dotnet --info
RUN node -v
RUN npm -v
RUN webpack -v
#RUN dotnet nuget add source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json -n nuget.org
RUN dotnet nuget list source
```

And the actual command in TeamCity to compile the code. This is the where it fails:

```
dotnet publish MyApi.sln -o C:\stage
```

Comment: Just as a side comment. Also getting this error randomly from multiple packages. Probability with which problem occurs is somehow between 0-20%.

Upgrading from .net 5 to .net 7 does not help.

Maybe it's possible to disable NuGet’s signature validation mode, but somehow puzzled why I need to do that one.

According to nuget documentation - maybe re-signing nuget package would help, but in my case problem occurs on different packages, not the same.

Suspect need to raise error to .net core itself, need for someone to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

Check first if it is related to [`NuGet/Announcements` issue 70](https://github.com/NuGet/Announcements/issues/70)

> ### The Microsoft author-signing certificate will be updated as soon as August 14th, 2023
>
> The current Microsoft author-signing certificate will be updated as soon as August 14th, 2023. If you validate that packages are author signed by Microsoft using a [NuGet client policy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/installing-signed-packages) or the [`verify`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/cli-reference/cli-ref-verify) command, you will need to take steps to avoid disruptions when installing Microsoft packages signed with the new certificate.
>
> If you are unsure if you will be impacted or want to see instructions to allow the new certificate, please see our blog post on the matter: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/microsoft-author-signing-certificate-update-2023/

The blog post mentioned:

> Action required: If you validate that packages are author-signed by Microsoft using a NuGet client policy or the `NuGet.exe verify` command, please follow these steps by August 14th, 2023 to avoid potential disruptions when installing new Microsoft packages. If you are unsure, we have outlined steps to check if you will be impacted.
>
> Microsoft uses an X.509 certificate to author-sign its NuGet packages. The current certificate will expire on October 5th, 2023. In late August 2023, a new certificate will replace it as the new Microsoft author-signing certificate for NuGet packages. Existing packages already signed with the older certificate will retain their existing signature, but the older certificate will soon no longer be used to sign packages.
>
> Current certificate SHA-256 fingerprint: `AA12DA22A49BCE7D5C1AE64CC1F3D892F150DA76140F210ABD2CBFFCA2C18A27`
>
> New certificate SHA-256 fingerprint: `566A31882BE208BE4422F7CFD66ED09F5D4524A5994F50CCC8B05EC0528C1353`
>
> #### Who will be impacted?
>
> - Customers who are using a NuGet client policy to enforce an allow list of trusted signers that includes Microsoft.
>
>   To tell if you have a [NuGet client policy](https://docs.microsoft.com/nuget/consume-packages/installing-signed-packages) configured, check for the following elements in your nuget.config. Keep in mind that you can have nuget.config files in [multiple locations with different scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior#config-file-locations-and-uses).
>
>   ```xml
>   <config>
>   <add key="signatureValidationMode" value="require" />
>   </config>
>
>   <trustedSigners>
>   <author name="Microsoft">
>       <certificate fingerprint="3F9001EA83C560D712C24CF213C3D312CB3BFF51EE89435D3430BD06B5D0EECE" hashAlgorithm="SHA256" allowUntrustedRoot="false" />
>       <certificate fingerprint="AA12DA22A49BCE7D5C1AE64CC1F3D892F150DA76140F210ABD2CBFFCA2C18A27" hashAlgorithm="SHA256" allowUntrustedRoot="false" />
>   </author>
>   </trustedSigners>
>   ```
> - Customers who use NuGet.exe verify to verify that signed packages are author-signed by Microsoft.
>
>   This will look like the following:
>
>   ```bash
>   NuGet.exe verify -Signatures <PackagePath> -CertificateFingerprint "3F9001EA83C560D712C24CF213C3D312CB3BFF51EE89435D3430BD06B5D0EECE;AA12DA22A49BCE7D5C1AE64CC1F3D892F150DA76140F210ABD2CBFFCA2C18A27"
>   ```
>
> If neither of the above scenarios apply to you, then you should be unaffected by the certificate update! Microsoft NuGet packages signed with the new certificate should install in the same way as packages signed with older certificates do.
>
> #### Allow the new Microsoft certificate Client policy
>
> If you are using a NuGet client policy to enforce an allow list of trusted signers, then you will need to add the new Microsoft certificate to your allow list to avoid disruptions when installing Microsoft packages signed with the new certificate. You should keep the older Microsoft certificates as well to continue installing Microsoft packages signed with older certificates. If you try to install one of these newer Microsoft packages without updating your trusted signers, you’ll get an [NU3034 error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/nu3034) and the package will fail to install.
>
> You can add the new Microsoft author-signing certificate by running the following command:
>
> ```bash
> NuGet.exe trusted-signers Add -Name Microsoft2023 -CertificateFingerprint 566A31882BE208BE4422F7CFD66ED09F5D4524A5994F50CCC8B05EC0528C1353 -FingerprintAlgorithm SHA256
> ```
>
> Or by adding the following elements that includes the old and new certificates to your nuget.config:
>
> ```xml
> <trustedSigners>
>   <author name="Microsoft">
>     <certificate fingerprint="3F9001EA83C560D712C24CF213C3D312CB3BFF51EE89435D3430BD06B5D0EECE" hashAlgorithm="SHA256" allowUntrustedRoot="false" />
>     <certificate fingerprint="AA12DA22A49BCE7D5C1AE64CC1F3D892F150DA76140F210ABD2CBFFCA2C18A27" hashAlgorithm="SHA256" allowUntrustedRoot="false" />
>     <certificate fingerprint="566A31882BE208BE4422F7CFD66ED09F5D4524A5994F50CCC8B05EC0528C1353" hashAlgorithm="SHA256" allowUntrustedRoot="false" />
>   </author>
> </trustedSigners>
> ```
>
> #### `NuGet.exe verify`
>
> Similarly, if you use `NuGet.exe verify` to verify that a signed package is author-signed by Microsoft, you’ll need to update the command to handle all certificates like so:
>
> ```bash
> NuGet.exe verify -Signatures <PackagePath> -CertificateFingerprint "3F9001EA83C560D712C24CF213C3D312CB3BFF51EE89435D3430BD06B5D0EECE;AA12DA22A49BCE7D5C1AE64CC1F3D892F150DA76140F210ABD2CBFFCA2C18A27;566A31882BE208BE4422F7CFD66ED09F5D4524A5994F50CCC8B05EC0528C1353"
> ```
>
> #### NuGet.org certificate update coming soon
>
> As a side note, the NuGet.org repository-signing certificate will be expiring not too long after the Microsoft author-signing certificate expires. You can expect a similar certificate update and instructional post for NuGet.org soon.

---

The OP adds:

> But why randomness occur - does somehow depends on build machine ? something else ?

If your CI/CD environment (TeamCity) uses a pool of build agents, then not all agents might be identically configured or might not have the same set of cached packages. An issue might manifest on one agent but not on another. Check the logs of the agents where failures occurred for any anomalies or errors.

Also, the first time a package is fetched, it is cached. If there is a corruption or an anomaly with a package, it might only manifest on agents that do not already have that package cached.  To clear the TeamCity cache, navigate to the `_work` directory on the build agent and remove the relevant directories. Or use [this option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69011868/6309)

Comment: But this failure occurs randomly. Re-signing nuget package is one way to solve it. But why randomness occur - does somehow depends on build machine ? something else ?

Comment: @TarmoPikaro I have edited the answer to address your comment. The first part was about "how can be walkarounded, how to fix properly?".